# How to crawl all webpages on website up to certain depth?

Tags: python, recursion, scrapy

I have a website and I would like to find a webpage with information about job vacancies. There is only one page usually with such information. So I start crawling with website and I manage to get all webpages up to certain depth. It works. But they are many times duplicated. Instead of lets say 45 pages I get 1000 pages. I know the reason why. The reason is that every time I call my "parse" function, it parses all the webpages on a certain webpage. So when I come to a new webpage, it crawls all webpages, out of which some have been crawled before.

1) I tried to make "items=[]" list out of parse function but I get some global error. I don't know how to get a list of unique webpages. When I have one, I will be able to choose the right one with simple url parsing. 
2) I also tried to have "Request" and "return items" in the "parse" function, but I get syntax error: return inside generator.

I am using DEPTH_LIMIT. Do I really need to use Rules ?

code:

```
import scrapy, urlparse, os
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import JobItem
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urljoin
from datetime import datetime


class JobSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    allowed_domains = ["www.gen-i.si"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.gen-i.si"]

    def parse(self, response):
        response.selector.remove_namespaces() #
        urls = response.xpath('//@href').extract()#choose all "href", either new websites either webpages on our website
        items = []


        base_url = get_base_url(response) #base url


        for url in urls:
            #we need only webpages, so we remove all websites and urls with strange characters
            if (url[0:4] != "http") and not any(x in url for x in ['%', ':', '?', '&']):

                item = JobItem()
                absolute_url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url,url)
                item["link"] = absolute_url
                if item not in items:
                    items.append(item)

                    yield item
                    yield Request(absolute_url, callback = self.parse)
        #return items
```

Comment: Read about [Crawl Spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider)

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I read about Crawl Spider but ..

Comment: Hey guys,
I would like to ask your for your ideas.
I would like to create a list of all unique webpages. How do I do that? It sounds like a simple task to me, great for some tutorial :)
The thing is, that for each call of the function "parse" I get a list of webpages (items) and these lists contain the same webpages. 
But I would like to have a unique list. I tried to create list "items = []" outside of "def parse" function, to just add new unique webpages, but I get NameError: global name 'items' is not defined. When I try to "return items", I get SyntaxError: return inside generator. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending `item` (a newly instantiated object), to your list `items`.  Since `item` is always a new `JobItem()` object, it will never exist in your list `items`.

To illustrate:

```
>>> class MyItem(object):
...   pass
...
>>> a = MyItem()
>>> b = MyItem()
>>> a.url = "abc"
>>> b.url = "abc"
>>> a == b
False
```

Just because they have one attribute that is the same, doesn't mean they are the same object.

Even if this worked though, you're resetting the list `items` everytime you call parse (ie. for each request), so you'll never really remove duplicates.

Instead, you would be better checking vs. the `absolute_url` itself, and putting the list at the spider level:

```
class JobSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    allowed_domains = ["www.gen-i.si"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.gen-i.si"]
    all_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        # remove "items = []"
        ...
        for url in urls:
            if (url[0:4] != "http") and not any(x in url for x in ['%', ':', '?', '&']):    
                absolute_url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, url)
                if absolute_url not in self.all_urls:
                    self.all_urls.append(absolute_url)
                    item = JobItem()
                    item['link'] = absolute_url

                    yield item
                    yield Request(absolute_url, callback = self.parse)
```

This functionality, however, would be better served by creating a `Dupefilter` instead ([see here for more information](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class)).  Additionally, I agree with @RodrigoNey, a `CrawlSpider` would likely better serve your purpose, and be more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Thank you @Rejected, that is exactly what I needed. To get out of the parse function loop to the spider level. Now I know, how to use "self". CrawlSpider and Dupefilter, that is the next level. When I learn more about Python, I might get there. For now it is important that my prototype is working. Later we might optimise it because we intend to use it for several tens of thousands of websites. Thank you very much again. Stackoverflow works fine. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a web crawler and ended up making a list of links that needed to be crawled, then once we went there it was deleted from that list and added to the crawled list. then you can use a `not in` search to either add/delete/etc.